# Setting up ELK stack on kubernetes using minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

After installing this is what my pods look like

```
Running pods
NAME                                          READY   STATUS                  RESTARTS   AGE
elk-elasticsearch-client-5ffc974f8-987zv      1/1     Running                 0          21m
elk-elasticsearch-curator-1582107120-4f2wm    0/1     Completed               0          19m
elk-elasticsearch-data-0                      0/1     Pending                 0          21m
elk-elasticsearch-exporter-84ff9b656d-t8vw2   1/1     Running                 0          21m
elk-elasticsearch-master-0                    1/1     Running                 0          21m
elk-elasticsearch-master-1                    1/1     Running                 0          20m
elk-filebeat-4sxn9                            0/2     Init:CrashLoopBackOff   9          21m
elk-kibana-77b97d7c69-d4jzz                   1/1     Running                 0          21m
elk-logstash-0                                0/2     Pending                 0          21m
```

So filebeat refuses to start.
Getting the logs from this node I get

```
Exiting: Couldn't connect to any of the configured Elasticsearch hosts. Errors: [Error connection to Elasticsearch http://elk-elasticsearch-client.elk.svc:9200: Get http://elk-elasticsearch-client.elk.svc:9200: lookup elk-elasticsearch-client.elk.svc on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host]
```

Also when trying to access the kibana node (the only node i can call using http) I get that it is not ready.

get pv:

```
pvc-9b9b13d8-48d2-4a79-a10c-8d1278554c75   4Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    default/data-elk-elasticsearch-master-0   standard                113m
pvc-d8b361d7-8e04-4300-a0f8-c79f7cea7e44   4Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    default/data-elk-elasticsearch-master-1   standard                112m
```

I'm running minikube with the none vm-driver which it tells me, does not respect the memory or cpu-flag. But I don't get it complaining about resources

```
kubectl version 1.17
docker version i 19.03.5, build 633a0ea838
minikube version 1.6.2
```

The elk stack was installed using helm.
I have the following versions:

- elasticsearch-1.32.2.tgz
- elasticsearch-curator-2.1.3.tgz
- elasticsearch-exporter-2.2.0.tgz
- filebeat-4.0.0.tgz
- kibana-3.2.6.tgz
- logstash-2.4.0.tgz

Running on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: No, I am not sure that I've given enough information. I just try my best.

Comment: Layout has been improved :)

Comment: can you please provide the reason why `elk-filebeat-4sxn9 ` is failing to start?.
Do this `oc describe pod elk-filebeat-4sxn9` and let me know the last couple of lines.

Comment: The `Running pods` clearly shows that pods are still pending. This seems like lack of resources. Can you get output from commands: `kubectl describe pod` for `elk-elasticsearch-data-0` and `elk-logstash-0` pods? This might have information why are they still pending. `filebeat` most likely is waiting for `elasticsearch` to be ready.

Comment: Why are you using tarballs instead of APT packages or existing Elastic containers?

Comment: I've dug a little further into this. I had to manually create some of the Physical Volumes, however right now I have the problem that it will not provision a gp2 sorage class  Warning  ProvisioningFailed  4m15s (x36 over 68m)  persistentvolume-controller  Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "gp2": Failed to get AWS Cloud Provider. GetCloudProvider returned <nil> instead

Answer (score 1):

Tearing everything down and then installing the required components from other helm-charts solved the issues. It may be that the charts I was using were not intended to run locally on minikube.